# Check If Initialized Slice Is Empty Without Relying On len()

Tags: go, time-complexity, slice

I have a use case where builtin len() function isn't appropriate to check if an initialized (non-nil) slice is empty or not.

How can I safely check if a slice is empty without len()?

I tried to index the first element, however, if it does not exist it would panic my program.

Comment: It's appropriate to use `len()` to tell if a slice has elements.

Comment: `len` is how you check length of a slice. How is inspecting the length of the slice not the appropriate way to see what the length is?

Comment: @icza I can't bother my algorithm with counting all elements within an array. As first of all, I do not need to know the length, I need to know if it's empty.

Comment: `len` doesn’t count elements, it returns the length field from the slice header. Use `len`

Comment: len of a slice is O(1) and not O(N) contrary to your assumption.

Comment: @KamiSama Initialized slices aren't nil.

Comment: @JimB could you post it as an answer so I can accept it.

Comment: @OluwafemiSule thanks. Wasn't aware that it's handled in such a manner.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> How can I safely check if a slice is empty without len()?

There is absolutely no reason to *not* use `len()`, so just use len as len is a O(1) operation.